# Why does this tweak to Ser's series expression for $\zeta(s)$ always yield $f(s)=s$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, binomial-coefficients, riemann-zeta

The following expressions for $\zeta(s)$ are valid for $s \in \mathbb{C}-\{1\}$:

By Helmut Hasse (1930):

$$\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{s-1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\ {n \choose k}\ \frac{1}{(k+1)^{s-1}}$$

By Joseph Ser (1926):

$$\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{s-1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n+2}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\ {n \choose k}\ \frac{1}{(k+1)^{s}}$$

Their equivalence is nicely explained [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.02044.pdf).

Made a tweak to the latter series and numerical evidence suggests that:

$$f(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\ {n \choose k}\ \frac{1}{(k+1)^{s}}$$

yields $f(s)=s$ for all $s$ (convergence is quite slow, but seems faster for negative $s$ and particularly at negative integers).

If true, why would this be the case?

*ADDED:*

Or formulated differently, is it true that:

$$f(s)=\lim_{N \to +\infty} H\left( N \right)+\sum _{n=1}^{N} \left( {
\frac {1}{n}\sum _{k=1}^{n}{\left( -1 \right) ^{k}{n\choose k}\frac { 1
}{ \left( k+1 \right) ^{s}}}} \right) = s$$

with $H(N)$ = the $N$-th [Harmonic Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number)?

Comment: Are you sure it converges? [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+n+%3D+1+to+infinity+of+1%2Fn+*+%28sum+from+k+%3D+0+to+n+of+%28-1%29%5Ek*binomial%28n%2C+k%29%2F%28k%2B1%29%5Es%29) says that the sum diverges, and numerical evidence suggests it only converges for $s$ in $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @VVejalla, yes, I am pretty sure it converges. Tested it in Maple and pari/gp, but you need to set the precision quite high to make it converge for non-integer values.

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/359460/does-this-series-related-to-the-hasse-ser-series-for-zetas-converge-for-a